# I am stuck on Precision Applying Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis, units

The stability of the Cesium Clock used as an atomic time standard is such that two Cesium clocks would gain or lose $1$ s with respect to each other in about $300,000$ y. If this same precision were applied to the distance between New York and San Francisco $(4139.23$ km $)$, by how much would successive measurements of this distance tend to differ?

Okay my solution to this was :-

Since we need to apply precision, I decided to divide $1$s by $300,000$ $=>$

$\frac 1 {300000} = 0.0000034$

But I absolutely have no idea why I did it.

So, once I got the no. of significant digits as $7$ in $0.0000034$,  I simply took the distance from New York to San Francisco and represented in 7 significant figures $=>$ $41.3923 \times 10^5$ km.

**But** the answer according to the book is $413$nm.

The step I did to find out the precision is horribly wrong and I seem to be stuck on it. Can someone please tell me where I lack the thinking to find out the precision?

**EDIT :-** All right. According to @trula answer I did the Precison calculation and it indeed comes to $\frac 1 {300000 \times 365 \times 24 \times 60 \times 60} = 0.38 \times 10^{-10}$s $=$ $3.8 \times 10^{-9}$s aka it comes in nano seconds.

But when I convert the Distance to metres it comes out to be $4139230$m for which if I take out the zeroes then it comes to $4.139230 \times 10^6$. Now am I doing something wrong here or am I stuck? Do i need to divide something or whatsoever?

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of dividing by 300.000 was not so bad, but you have not to divide by years but by seconds so divide by 300.000*365*24*60*60 and multiply the result with the distance in m
the precision of the clock is per 1s, the same precision for 1m you want.

Comment: Ok. I solved the precision problem by dividing 1s by 300000 * 365*24*60*60 = 3.8 * (10^9).  But converting the distance to meters gives me 4139230 m for which if I take out the zeroes it would end up as 4.139230 * (10 ^ 6) m ........... (TT) Can't seem to solve further than that.

What exactly I don't seem to understand here is how to apply that precision of nano metres into the distance

Comment: You divide the given 4139230m by the number I told you. if you assume the precision per m is the same as the precision per s.

Comment: Why should I divide the distance with 3.8 * (10^9) ? Is there any intended logic behind it that I may be missing?

Comment: It has to do with "this same precision" how would you describe the precision of the clock in 1 s, in 1 min, in 1 day ? in 1s the precision ist 1/(3,8*10^9) s so <ou are sure it is 1.000000000 s and not  1.000000001 .Now suppose wie can measure 1m with the same prezission ,  then 1000m have 1000 time tis precision and so on.